# Whats the difference between i386,i686 etc processors?

Tags: cpu, architecture

Which one is latest or normally used in computers today ? What is the type of pentium 4 and Core 2 duo?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i386 is for extremely old CPU generation dating before Pentium.

i686 is post Pentium generation.

No one today have i386, they are at least 15 years old.

That being said, i386 marks a 'compatibility' build and should work on ANY 32bit x86 CPU. i686 may or may not use MMX, SSE and more extensions.

Comment: Are applications written for i386 compatible with i686?

Comment: i686 can always run i386. the reverse is not always true.

Comment: "No one today have i386, they are at least 15 years old." ... khm, khm ... well, wouldn't you believe it but ... :-)))

Comment: @Rook you have it, right?

Answer (score 0):

The processors have different instruction extensions.
But, the core instructions are the same - 386.

Extensions - as the SSE3 - Streaming SIMD Extensions 3,
are explained in Wikipedia.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE3
```

And, capabilities differ as different version of the chips anre manufactured.
See the Intel site:

```
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark.html#@Processors
```